# HOw to trim URL?

Tags: c#

I am designing a web page using asp.net with c# as programming language in which there is a text box where user has to paste you tube video url

and I would like do programming in such a way so that when user paste video url then

only video id remain and all other data get trimmed.

for example this is original video url

https://youtu.be/Px1AeJQ_vF4

and after trimmed programming it should remain

Px1AeJQ_vF4

this id only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you either want the Path or the Path and the query (the part after `?`).

For path alone you can use [`Uri` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1) (note that it returns the value with a leading `/`):

```
string path = new Uri("https://youtu.be/Px1AeJQ_vF4?t=5").LocalPath.Substring(1);
// outputs Px1AeJQ_vF4
```

For the path and the query, you just need to change to `PathAndQuery`. Again, it returns a leading `/` on the path:

```
string pathAndQuery = new Uri("https://youtu.be/Px1AeJQ_vF4?t=5").PathAndQuery.Substring(1);
// outputs Px1AeJQ_vF4?t=5
```

There's also [`UriBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netcore-3.1) which is capable of constructing and deconstructing a URL, should you want to do more advanced manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string url = "https://youtu.be/Px1AeJQ_vF4";  
string[] urlSplit= url.Split("/");  
string last = urlSplit.Last()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following code :

```
    string text = "https://youtu.be/Px1AeJQ_vF4";
    var res = text.Split('/');
    Console.WriteLine(res[res.Length-1]);
```